# Can my smartphone's microphones get damaged by recording loud sounds?

Tags: microphone

I recorded some songs with my Android  phone from another phone at maximum volume.
Will this damage my Android microphones?

Comment: The microphones are exposed to the same level of mechanical stimulation whether you're recording or not.

Answer (score 1):

A loud rock concert will have higher sound pressure levels (SPL) than any smartphone speaker is capable of generating. Even when not recording, such sound pressure levels will vibrate the microphone transducers. Sonic booms and explosions are where damage might start.

Trying to record very loud sounds like near a concert PA system or at an airport tarmac, etc. most likely would result in distortion and clipping (bad quality audio), but no permanent damage.

To give an exact figure where damage would occur would require knowing more about the specific microphone your phone uses, and even then its datasheet is unlikely to provide a figure for irreversible damage from a certain SPL. Some types of microphones, such as ribbon microphones used in studios, could potentially be ruptured or torn by sudden high pressure, such as from a close-proximity gunshot. Different types of microphones (dynamic, condenser, ribbon) have different tolerances for SPL, but even within a microphone type there are wide variations depending on materials and design.

Short answer: no, you won't damage a microphone from smartphone-generated sound.